# RecyclerView layout broken after returning from launched activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using classic implementation of RecyclerView with OnItemClickListener.

Relevant from adapter :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SmokesViewHolder smokesViewHolder, int i){
        String ci = smokeMapList.get(i);

        smokesViewHolder.vRowName.setText(ci);
        switch (ci) {
            case "de_dust2":
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.de_dust2).transform(new CircleTransform()).fit().centerCrop().into(smokesViewHolder.vRowImage);
                break;
...(more stuff here)
            default:
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.de_train).transform(new CircleTransform()).fit().centerCrop().into(smokesViewHolder.vRowImage);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Which gives layout normally like this : [imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXce3.jpg)

However, one user is reporting an issue with layout looking like this

[image]

After clicking on any item in the list, opening new activity and then returning back into recycler. Any scrolling fixes it. (Don't mind different color scheme, user is using "night mode theme") Reported phone and version is "Moto G 2.gen 4g. 5.0.2", however, I can't reproduce the issue on my side (different phone) or emulator.

Anyone has any idea what could cause this or how could I reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue.What I have done is added bottom padding for reyclerview and made clipToPadding false.I know this is not the right solution.But it worked for me.

```
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```